# Is it possible to execute onDraw() right after invalidate(Rect)?

Tags: java, android, ondraw, invalidation

I added a breakpoint in my onDraw() method and noticed that my debugger only gets there after the method in which invalidate(rect) is, ends. Is it possible to be called right after?
Because I need to call invalidate(rect) twice in my method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Calling `invalidate()` is a signal to the framework that a portion of the screen is dirty and needs to be redrawn. The actual drawing doesn't happen immediately... it happens the next time through the main thread's event queue.

Comment: Hmm well, I can implement another way of do it. Btw, if I want my dirty zone two be like to rectangles separated, if I do invalidate(rect1) then invalidate(rect2) both rectangles will be invalidated right?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such problem with me and as alex saying it'll not happen. I can suggest one workaround that u can have your own implementation of `onDraw()` method with different name like `myOnDraw()` only when it should be not very heavy. so instead calling or depending upon `onDraw()` to be called immediately u can call that method which will work for u when u need it.

Comment: And how would myOnDraw() draw things in the View if it's not a native android method?

Comment: u need only canvas ref for that.. and probably you have overridden  onDraw() in your class.